# Why is my Silverlight usercontrol property null?

Tags: silverlight

I have a usercontrol:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Text="Text for"></TextBlock> 
    </Grid>
```

It has a cs file:

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text + MyProperty;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add this usercontrol programatically to another user control:

```
            UserControls.MyUserControl myUserControl = new UserControls.MyUserControl();
            myUserControl.MyProperty = "Something";
            MyStackPanel.Children.Add(myUserControl);
```

I thought I've done something like this before without any issues, but in this case MyProperty is always null.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: +1 for providing XAML *and* code. Always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine as-is except for when you are calling `DoSomething()`. You should avoid *GUI interaction* in the constructor of a control for many reasons (not the least of which is that your property is not yet set as pointed out by Mark Hall). *I do not however recommend adding different constructors just to take initial properties*.

You simply want to defer that call to the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event of the control.

### Assuming you set the event in the Xaml like this:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="MyUserControl" 
    ...
    Loaded="Page_Loaded">
```

### Your code would look like:

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text + MyProperty;
    }
}
```

### If you want to set the *Loaded* event in code it would just look like:

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Page_Loaded; 
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text + MyProperty;
    }
}
```

The it is just down to you setting all your desired properties after construction, but before the page is loaded as you are doing already.

```
UserControls.MyUserControl myUserControl = new UserControls.MyUserControl();
myUserControl.MyProperty = "Something";
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(myUserControl); // This makes it visible when Loaded event is called
```

Comment: Thank you.  Eventually I came around to the solution Mark posted, but I think this solution is more in tune with what I wanted.  For some reason I completely forgot about Page_Loaded.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are calling `DoSomething` in your contructor before you have set `MyProperty` so `MyProperty` is equal to null. If you want the data to be there when the `UserControl` is created you can set it in the Constructor.

i.e.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyUserControl()   //Default Constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyUserControl(string MyData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyProperty = MyData;
        DoSomething();
    }
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text + MyProperty;
    }

}
```

and create it like this.

```
MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl(" Something");
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(myUserControl);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I could not for some reason understand what I was doing wrong.  I did end up figuring out that if I created another constructor and then set the property there it would work.

Comment: @dtc I thought about mentioning the Load Event, but that is as far as it got. I am glad that you were able to work out your problem.